# VueJs get url query

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vue.js, vue-router

I'm developing a website with vuejs and at this moment I'm with a problem, I need to get the URL query (page) from a URL like this websitename.com/user/?page=1 but the `this.$router.query.page` gives me an error (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'page' of undefined)

Does someone know something about this problem and can help me?

PS: I can set the query page using

```
this.$router.push({name: 'userIndex', query: { page: '123' } });
```

and I can get the URL normal params like the

```
userID -> (websitename.com/user/:userId | websitename.com/user/1)
```

but I can't get any query parameter.

Answer (score 185, accepted):

I think you can simple call like this, this will give you result value.

```
this.$route.query.page
```

Look image $route is object in Vue Instance and you can access with this keyword and next you can select object properties like above one :

[image]

Have a look Vue-router document for selecting queries value :

[Vue Router Object](http://router.vuejs.org/en/api/route-object.html)

Comment: your answer is right, but the console.log works also after i change the event handler where has de call to the router query to "created"

Answer (score 27):

You can also get them with pure javascript.

For example:

```
new URL(location.href).searchParams.get('page')
```

For this url: **websitename.com/user/?page=1**, it would return a value of **1**

Answer (score 16):

Current route properties are present in `this.$route`, `this.$router` is the instance of router object which gives the configuration of the router. You can get the current route query using `this.$route.query`

Answer (score 12):

In my case I `console.log(this.$route)` and returned the fullPath:

```
console.js:
fullPath: "/solicitud/MX/666",
params: {market: "MX", id: "666"},
path: "/solicitud/MX/666"

console.js: /solicitud/MX/666
```

Answer (score 1):

For the url either having query param or as route path. use: `this.$router.currentRoute._value`. It has all the properties of the url that you may want

**This is have all the routes like for url: https://localhost:8880/2?isExternal=true**

```js
this.$router.currentRoute._value.params.studentId 

note: studentId is the route param name.
output: will return 2
```

**This is have all the query params like: https://localhost:8880/2?isExternal=true**

```js
this.$router.currentRoute._value.query.isExternal 

output: will return value of isExternal, that is: true
```

[image]