# How do I access the $route.params variable in the component resolve function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I have a simple website that uses async components. Here's an example of one:

```
Vue.component('news', function(resolve, reject){

    let data = {
        action: 'load_news_article',
        article_id: 0 // need the article ID here
    };

    $.post(window.ajax_url, data, function(r){
        r = JSON.parse(r);

        if( r.success ) {
            resolve({
                template: r.data
            });
        }
    });
});
```

I have dynamic routes that map to this component as well. Those `<router-link>` URL's look like `/news/some-article`. I created the route as `/news/:article` in the router.

How can I access the `article` variable before firing my ajax? My goal is to pass it to the server along with the initial component load. If Vue doesn't allow that, then I can't think of any other way other than letting the router navigate the page, then I parse the new URL with my own JS.

It's a really simple website. There's only 5 components (one for each page) and only this one is dynamic. So I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require me to overhaul my structure.

Comment: access article id from... where?

Comment: related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42309986/vuejs-get-url-query

Comment: I don't think that's related. He's not using async components. When I console.log `this` in my component function, it's undefined.

Comment: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vue-router-with-async-component-to-acquire-route-param/2599